# javascript while() loop creates a line of cells instead of a table

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop

Does any one on the Earth knows why this while loop doesn't work as expected?

I wanted it to create an HTML table but it makes a weird line of cells.

Take a look.....

```js
var t = "<table>", i = 10 ; //h = 10;

    while(i--> 0) {
        //here was the problem declare the h var here
        var h =10;
        t += "<tr>";
            while (h-->0) {
                t += "<td> "+ h + "</td>";
            }
        t += "</tr>";
    }

    t += "</table>";
    $("body").append($(t));
```

```css
    html,body {
    margin-top:20px;
    height:100%;
    }

    td {
    border:1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script  src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>
            JS Bin
            </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a `for` loop?

Comment: i was ;;;; but to write a while loop is easier like this `while(i--){}`
:::::::you don't need `i-->0`

Answer (score 3):

You don't reset `h` to `10`. Once it went to `0` for `i=9` (first iteration of `i`), it stays at `0`.

Reset it at the beginning of the external loop :

```
var t="<table>",i=10;
while(i-->0){
  var h = 10;
  t+="<tr>";
  while(h-->0){t+="<td>"+h+"</td>";}
  t+="</tr>";
}
t+="</table>";
$("body").append(t); // no need for $(t) here
```

Using `for` statements here might help keep the initialization near the loop and doesn't make the program less concise (which looks like what you tried to achieve) :

```
var t="<table>";
for(var i=10;i--;){
  t+="<tr>";
  for(var h=10;h--;) t+="<td>"+h+"</td>";
  t+="</tr>";
}
t+="</table>";
$("body").append(t);
```

This also makes it obvious when you forget the `var` declaration (which is one of the common bugs in JS programs).

Comment: but h was set on global scope earlier   however i will try

Comment: The global scope of `h` means that its value will be changed thoughout your program, not that it will keep the same initial value inside "local" scope.

Comment: unlike `var i=10;for(/*no declaration*/;i>0;i--)`